# Hide score file in java game

Tags: java, file, exe

I made a Java game and it records the high scores in a `.dat` file, then I converted the game into an `.exe` file. However, when I play the `.exe` file and it records the score, the `highscores.dat` appears in whatever directory the `.exe` is located. I'm not very familiar with files processing in java aside from creating and reading them using the basic input streams and output streams. Is there any way to hide the score file so that if I give the game to someone the `highscores.dat` won't appear in their computer?

Comment: Maybe you can create the file and set the hidden attribute on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- On **Windows** you could store your file in the `%appdata%/<gamename>/highscores.dat` directory without admin persmissions.
- On **Linux** you could chose for the directory `~/.<gamename>/highscores.dat`
- On **Mac OSX** you could chose the directory `/Users/<USERNAME>/Library/Application Support/<gamename>/highscores.dat`

If you do it like this, the file wont be showing up on your games' folder. This has also the advantage of maintaining the highscores data, even when you move your game to another location.

Comment: I'd like to add, this also has to added advantage of your highscores persisting if you move the location of your game.

Comment: If I may ask, do I put %appdata%/<gamename>/highscores.dat in the FileInputStream and FileOutputStream? Like FileInputStream("%appdata%/<gamename>/highscores.dat")? Or do I put it somewhere else?

Comment: You could use the method System.getenv("APPDATA") for getting the path of %appdata%

Comment: I'm not quite sure what to put in the <gamename>. Is it the filename of the .exe file or the name of the java class?

Comment: You could put there whatever you want, but most probably you want to put your gamename in there. like "crazyawsomegame" :-). It is just a folder

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much! (I forgot about the check mark thingy for correct answers. Sorry :P)

Comment: I would upvote if I could, but I can't. :( It says 15 required reputation and, sadly, I don't have enough reputation :(

Answer (score 0):

May be you can go with any encryption technique and then write it on the score file.

Comment: I don't think OP's concern is hacking the game. I think the concern is the file actually showing up on the users computer. I'd like to add that this probably wouldn't be secure. The key would have to be stored in the exe somewhere, in which case you could just find it.